# How to use only one node for a Condor cluster job?

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, condor

I need to run lots of jobs (a pipeline) on a Condor cluster but it has to be on one node. So I need to do 2 things:

- How do I ask Condor for an available node?
- How do I tell Condor to run a job on that node?

I imagine this is very simple, but I'm deep in the docs with no luck.

Comment: Condor has an option where you can pass it a DAG that describes the jobs you want to run. I'd use that to specify the dependencies, even if they do imply a strict ordering.

Comment: Will this let me specify a specific node?

Comment: It sounds like I'm asking the impossible... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340004/condor-job-using-dag-with-some-jobs-needing-to-run-the-same-host?rq=1

Comment: @CornSmith It is very much possible. See my answer here and on your linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set a job requirement to run on a specific node.

```
requirements = $(requirements) && (TARGET.Machine == "somenode")
```

Selection of that node is up to you. If you use a DAG you can have a "node selection" job and then rewrite submit files as I outline here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27590992/174430.